# Desired Output using list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have a list and a dictionary in the following manner:

```
lista = [
    ['Pasta', 'is', 'bad'],
    ['Pasta', 'is', 'good', 'and','is','expensive']
]

dica = {
    'Pasta': 0,
     'is': 0,
     'bad': 0,
     'good': 0,
     'and': 0,
     'expensive': 0
}
```

I would like to take each sublist in the list and apply the dictionary to it, creating a list of dictionaries - one for each list - where the value for each key is the number of times that key appears in the sublist.

```
fin_dict = {
    {
        'Pasta': 1,
        'is': 1,
        'bad': 1,
        'good': 0,
        'and': 0,
        'expensive': 0
    },
    {
        'Pasta': 1,
        'is': 2,
        'bad': 0,
        'good': 1,
        'and': 1,
        'expensive': 1
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have written above would be producing a `set` of `dict`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: The output is not valid Python

Comment: Yeah it is creating a set of dicts, i dont mind if its a list too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def count_items(dic, lst):
    counts = dict(dic)
    for x in lst:
        counts[x] += 1
    return counts

lista=[['Pasta', 'is', 'bad'],['Pasta', 'is', 'good', 'and','is','expensive']]

dica={'Pasta': 0,'is': 0,'bad': 0,'good': 0,'and': 0,'expensive': 0}

print([count_items(dica, lista[0]), count_items(dica, lista[1])])

# prints [{'Pasta': 1, 'is': 1, 'bad': 1, 'good': 0, 'and': 0, 'expensive': 0}, {'Pasta': 1, 'is': 2, 'bad': 0, 'good': 1, 'and': 1, 'expensive': 1}]
```

(This solution assumes that fin_dict is a list and all items in the input list are in the dictionary.)

Comment: This helped i changed my code accordingly:
def sub_list(a):
    x=dict(dica)
    for i in a:
            x[i]+=1
    return x 
fin_list=[sub_list(i) for i in lista]
print(fin_list)

Answer (score 0):

I explained details in the following script:

```py
lista=[['Pasta', 'is', 'bad'],['Pasta', 'is', 'good', 'and','is','expensive']]

dica={'Pasta': 0,'is': 0,'bad': 0,'good': 0,'and': 0,'expensive': 0}

# Create an empty array to store dictionaries.
myList = []

for i in range(len(lista)):
    # Append `dica` in each iteration to get a reference of it.
    myList.append(dica)
    # Iterate through `dica` keys.
    for key in dica:
        # Iterate through list elements in lista.
        for listElem in lista[i]:
            # Check if the `key` is equal to the value in list,
            # in other words, count the occurences of list elements.
            if key == listElem:
                myList[i][key] += 1
print(myList)
```

**Note:** Your requested type of output is not possible as far as I know and I also think that you didn't meant to use `dictionary` so I made it to output in a `list`.

**Output:**

```py
[{'Pasta': 2, 'is': 3, 'bad': 1, 'good': 1, 'and': 1, 'expensive': 1}, {'Pasta': 2, 'is': 3, 'bad': 1, 'good': 1, 'and': 1, 'expensive': 1}]
```